# Extracting and Finding Word Meanings in Flutter PDF Viewer

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I'm developing a Flutter application where I aim to enable users to tap on words within a PDF document and retrieve their meanings through an API call. I'm utilizing the flutter_pdfview package for displaying PDFs and have implemented tap event detection to identify coordinates of tapped words.

However, I'm encountering difficulties in accurately extracting individual words from the PDF document based on the tapped coordinates. The current approach involves retrieving text content of the tapped page but lacks precision in isolating specific words.

Here's an overview of what I've attempted:

Used the flutter_pdfview package to render PDFs within the app.
Implemented tap event detection to capture coordinates of tapped words.
Retrieved text content of the tapped page but struggled with isolating words precisely.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.